# Return statements in try/catch block Java

Tags: java, try-catch

Suppose I have the following:

```
class NegativeException extends RuntimeException {
}

class ZeroException extends NegativeException {
}

class Driver {
    static boolean Marathon(int a) {
        try {
            if (a < 0)
                throw new NegativeException();
            else if (a == 0)
                throw new ZeroException();
            else if (a >= 42)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        } catch (ZeroException e) {
            System.out.println("Use natural number");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("One last thing");
        }
        System.out.println("All done.");
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* One last thing */
        /* true */
        System.out.println(Marathon(100));


        System.out.println(Marathon(0));
        System.out.println(Marathon(-5));

    }
}
```

What I'm trying to understand is why doesn't the line "All done" not execute when use the first line of our main method is fired? `Marathon(100)`

It seems that the `finally` statement executes and THEN the `return` statement is outputted. I know that the `finally` block will always execute, regardless of what happens. However, I can't seem to grasp on how return statements affect the  flow of the `try catch` blocks. Are there a set of rules that apply when trying to return from  `try-cath-finally` blocks?

Comment: *"class ZeroException extends NegativeException"* Um.... Remember, "extends" means there's an "is a" relationship. "0 is a negative" is not true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I'm trying to understand is why doesn't the line "All done" not execute when use the first line of our main method is fired? Marathon(100)

Because `a >= 42` is true, and so you do:

```
return true;
```

...which immediately transfers control to the `finally` block; at the end of the `finally` block, the function returns (*without* running any lines *following* the `finally` block). That is, `return` doesn't just set a return value, it terminates the function at that point, after running any outstanding `finally` blocks.

If you want execution to continue, you'd write to a variable and then have a single `return` at the end:

```
static boolean Marathon(int a) {
    boolean rv = false;
    try {
        if (a < 0)
            throw new NegativeException();
        else if (a == 0)
            throw new ZeroException();
        else if (a >= 42)
            rv = true;
    } catch (ZeroException e) {
        System.out.println("Use natural number");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("One last thing");
    }
    System.out.println("All done.");
    return rv;
}
```

---

More on `return` within `try` and `catch`: If you issue a `return` from within a `try` that has a `finally` block, it immediately transfers control to the `finally` block. When the end of that block is reached, the function terminates (*without* running any code *after* the `finally` block, unless you have nested `finally` blocks or similar). The same thing happens if you `return` from within a `catch`.

So for instance:

```
try {
    if (someCondition) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (someOtherCondition) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Got here because of exception");
    return 2;
}
finally {
    System.out.println("Got here");
}
System.out.println("May not have gotten here");
return 3;
```

`"Got here"` will **always** be output, no matter what; that's the point of `finally` clauses, they **always** get executed.

`"Got here because of exception"` will only be output if `someOtherCondition` is true (and will be output before `"Got here"`), in which case the function returns normally with the value `1`.

`"May not have gotten here"` will not be output if either `someCondition` or `someOtherCondition` is true, because of the `return`s in the `try` and `catch` blocks.

If neither condition is true, you see `"May not have gotten here"` followed by `"Got here"` and the function returns `3`.

Note that the `return` in the `catch` block means that the function returns *normally* (with the value `2`) when `someOtherCondition` is true, it doesn't throw. If you didn't have the `return` there and `someOtherCondition` were true, you'd see the `"Got here because of exception"` and the `"Got here"` and then the function would terminate with a throw (no return value at all), and would not output `"May not have gotten here"`.

Last but not least: If you have a `return` in a `finally` block, that `return` "wins": Even if you're in the `finally` block because you've already issued a `return`, a `return` in the finally block supercedes it, making the function return the value the `finally` said, not the earlier one.

Comment: @JBNizet: Right: *"...it terminates the function at that point (barring `finally` clauses and such)"* means "other than `finally` clauses and such" -- e.g., they **will** get executed. I'll reword, perhaps "barring" isn't clear to everyone.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Great! This just clarified it all! Thank you!

Comment: @Dimitri: Glad that helped. I folded that stuff into the answer. :-)

Comment: @Dimitri: Gah! Sorry, fixed -- see, you're an expert now!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just making sure I cover all my tracks! :)